# React Three Fiber Drei Billboard with Texture

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I´m using React Three Fiber with "Drei" and want to use the the billboards. But I could only figure out how to change the color of the billboard, but not how to add a texture.

I tried it like that, but can't find any documentation on billboards and don`t know what arguments i can pass.

```
<Billboard map={textureBillboard}/>
```

Here you see how to change color, but not how to add a texture:

https://drei.react-spring.io/?path=/story/abstractions-billboard--billboard-st

Hope someone can help me.

thanks

Comment: billborad is just a plane, dreis plane component to be exact. you must give it a material as a child or write material-map which will write map into the default material.

Answer (score 1):

you can add texture as a meshBasicMaterial:

```
<Billboard
   position={[0,7,1]}
   args = {[44,30]}>
   <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" map = {billboardTexture}/>
</Billboard>
```